# Software library to assign label to keywords

Tags: library

Is there any software library that I can use that takes these keywords as an input, and returns a label to describe the topic?

I'm using Python, so ideally a Python library, but I don't mind changing the language since I'm currently doing my research, and haven't started the implementation yet.

By label, I mean a word that is a common association to all the words in the input set. If there are multiple results, then I just need the best match.

Example:

Input:   `["Church","Priest","God","Prayer"]`

Output:  `"Religion"`

Comment: It looks like you are looking for an AI library or a library that you can train to do that

Comment: @AidenGrossman the "NLP" tag stands for "natural language processing". For those not familiar with it (like us two) it indeed looks like AI :)

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details, e.g. what language, what specific functionality you need (just topic classification or clustering and word sense disambiguation as well), etc.

Comment: One thing to clear up especially is your meaning of *title*. Your example returns only one word, which I do not consider a title. You are going to need very different software if it has to return "In church, the priest addressed God in a prayer". The way it looks now, you only need word association software.

Comment: I've edited the question to add some explanation.

Comment: @Izzy Actually NLP is quite an inappropriate tag for this, someone edited my question and added the tag. I've removed it now.

Comment: @JanDoggen, I think a word association software might be what I need. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If that's not [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), you might need to put additional examples (or explicitly clarify: how is the connection made between your keywords and the "label"?) – to me it looked exactly like that (though I was not the one adding that tag). I've added the more generic "text-processing" just now, as "library" alone is a bit broad. Feel free to adjust with another edit :)

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps WordNet (https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) could be of some interest to you.

Comment: @Izzy, the appropriate tag is topic-modelling, but as I do not have enough rep, I cannot create a tag that is not very common.

Comment: @GovernorBandicoot I'm not sure whether a single question justifies a tag. But you could [edit] your question and include some of the details gathered by the comments – including that term. That would make them more obvious and easier to find (without reading a long list of comments), and thus increase chances for answers.